# Parse a decimal value from a String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, decimal

I have a Ruby String that contains decimal-containing numbers. What's the best way to convert this into a decimal (fixed-point)?

"Best" means:

- Reliable given a wide range of input options
- Simple to write
- Easy to read
- DRY

...in roughly that order.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(Found it myself after a bit of digging)

[BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/classes/BigDecimal.html) is the standard Ruby fixed-point type, and it's constructor takes a String and handles the parsing for you:

```
BigDecimal.new("123.45")
```

Comment: You actually cant for X number of days (now elapsed)... besides I figured I'd give others a chance to contribute.

Comment: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.